# Switch with multiple services alternative

Tags: java, service, switch-statement

I have a switch calling multiple services like:

```
switch (condition) {
case 1:
    return service1.methodA(args....);
case 2:
    return service2.methodX(args....);
case 3:
    return service3.methodZ(args....);
.
.
.
default:
    break;
}
```

What its the best way for implement this?

The services are @Autowired and returning the same object.

Comment: are service implementation not implementing interface?

Comment: Welcome Daniel. What are methodA, methodX and methodZ returning?

Comment: the services returning the same object

Answer (score -1):

You could make them all implement a common interface:

```
interface YourCommonServiceName {
    YourReturnObject yourMethodName(/* your arguments */);
}
```

Then initially you could add all the services to a map, depending on their condition:

```
private final Map<Integer, YourCommonServiceName> services;

@Autowired
public YourClass(YourCommonServiceName serviceA, YourCommonServiceName serviceB, /* ... */) {
    Map<Integer, YourCommonServiceName> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(1, serviceA);
    map.put(2, serviceB);
    // ...

    services = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Then you can just call the `services`-map with the condition as argument:

```
YourCommonServiceName service = services.get(condition);
if(service == null) {
    // do something if nothing matches
    return;
}
```

And then invoke the method with the arguments:

```
YourReturnObject o = service.yourMethodName(args...);
```

You can create that map also directly in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public Map<Integer, YourCommonServiceName> services(YourCommonServiceName serviceA, YourCommonServiceName serviceB, ...) {
    Map<Integer, YourCommonServiceName> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(1, serviceA);
    map.put(2, serviceB);
    // ...

    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

And then inject that `Map` inside your other class:

```
public YourClass(Map<Integer, YourCommonServiceName> services) {
    this.services = services;
}
```

Comment: It depends on the usecase but instantiating all services might not be the best option if you want to use only one of them. Not sure what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: i forgot to mention that the services are with @Autowired

Comment: @DanielBarjola see my update, you can initialize the map in the constructor and use constructor injection of your services

Comment: @Lino thanks! its works, but I have like 12 services, its good to make the constructor with a lot of services in the arguments?

Comment: @DanielBarjola see the other edit, you can use a `Configuration` class to not clutter your main logic